# Apache redirect to perl script

Tags: apache, perl, redirect, awstats

I'm currently using Apache's vhosts configuration to redirect request to the server, e.g.

```
<VirtualHost IP:80>
ServerName http://domain.info
Redirect / http://otherdomain.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost IP:80>
ServerName http://subdomain.domain.info
Redirect / http://domain:port
</VirtualHost>
```

Now I installed AWstats which can be started by using the command

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/awstats.pl
```

I assume that if I add this block to vhosts

```
<VirtualHost IP:80>
ServerName http://stats.domain.info
Redirect / http://domain.info/cgi-bin/awstats.pl
</VirtualHost>
```

I can remote-access AWstats using

```
http://domain.info/cgi-bin/awstats.pl
```

but all I get is

```
http://otherdomain.comcgi-bin/awstats.pl
```

What am I doing wrong?

Greetz
holgrich

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is still open, but for now I used a workaround:

```
<VirtualHost IP:80>
ServerName http://domain.info
[Redirect to local html that contains frame forwarding]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost IP:80>
ServerName http://subdomain.domain.info
Redirect / http://domain:port
</VirtualHost>
```

Now this works

```
<VirtualHost IP:80>
ServerName http://stats.domain.info
Redirect / http://domain.info/cgi-bin/awstats.pl
</VirtualHost>
```

So that I can remote-access AWstats using

```
http://domain.info/cgi-bin/awstats.pl
```